# CSS Page breaking content with top margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, page-break

I need to print invoice with unknown number of items, and at the end of the invoice there is terms and conditions that is also - unknown number of lines.

So i have something similar to this:

```html
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="marginTop"></div>
    <div class="invoicecontent"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="marginTop"></div>
    <div class="invoicecontent"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="page">
    <div class="marginTop"></div>
    <div class="invoicecontent"></div>
    <div class="termsAndConditions"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

So now the page has a background image, that contains the identity of the company, and at the top there is logo. In the `div` of `marginTop` I am skipping number of lines so there is nothing to be printed their.

So in invoice content I always have it in the right place.

Now the terms and conditions comes as a variable that holds a text of html, the user will type it and i will read it and show it here.

What I want, that if the customer entered long term and conditions I want to break it into pages. But the thing is I cannot break it because i don't  know where to break exactly, as it can be any thing especially if it contains `html` code. And I want when it got printed out the top margin should be always their.

Can anyone give me any clues?

I can only use simple `JavaScript`, I cannot use `jQuery`, and I cannot get the height of the content after page load, any `JavaScript` should be used while rendering. I have tried to do that but it did not work.

Comment: Look, you have a lot of words here and, for me, it hard to understand with quick read (I guess that the most of the people here have no extra time). My propose to you is to short the question. Just give us the problematic html and say, I want to cut here or there. But maybe it's just me..

Comment: I think the length of the question is perfect

Comment: @MoshFeu i dont think that what i have written is enough, simply i would say that i want a break by page with margin on the top, but that will never be clear to you and you will end up giving me wrong solutions that i have already tried.

Comment: No, what I meant is that just add an **example html**, and say, I want to cut it here or there.